# Togglz with Spring @Configuration bean

Tags: spring, togglz

I'm trying to implement Togglz & Spring using @Configuration beans rather than XML. I'm not sure how to configure the return type of the Configuration bean. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class SystemClockConfig {

    @Bean
    public SystemClock plainSystemClock() {
        return new PlainSystemClock();
    }

    @Bean
    public SystemClock awesomeSystemClock() {
        return new AwesomeSystemClock();
    }

    @Bean
    public FeatureProxyFactoryBean systemClock() {
        FeatureProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new FeatureProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactoryBean.setActive(awesomeSystemClock());
        proxyFactoryBean.setInactive(plainSystemClock());
        proxyFactoryBean.setFeature(Features.AWESOME_SYSTEM_CLOCK.name());
        proxyFactoryBean.setProxyType(SystemClock.class);
        return proxyFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

The `systemClock` method returns a `FeatureProxyFactoryBean` but the clients of this bean require a `SystemClock`. Of course, the compiler freaks over this.

I imagine it just works when XML config is used. How should I approach it when using a configuration bean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert for the Java Config configuration style of Spring, but I guess your `systemClock()` method should return a proxy created with the FeatureProxyFactoryBean. Something like this:

```
@Bean
public SystemClock systemClock() {
    FeatureProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new FeatureProxyFactoryBean();
    proxyFactoryBean.setActive(awesomeSystemClock());
    proxyFactoryBean.setInactive(plainSystemClock());
    proxyFactoryBean.setFeature(Features.AWESOME_SYSTEM_CLOCK.name());
    proxyFactoryBean.setProxyType(SystemClock.class);
    return (SystemClock) proxyFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the common way to use FactoryBeans with Spring Java Config.

Comment: this implementation is in case of using feature toggles useless because your implementation will be discovered once since it is provided as singleton

Comment: FeatureProxyFactoryBean will create a proxy which will dispatch method calls to the correct instance. So this will work fine.

Comment: This method declares to return a FeatureProxyFactoryBean, but you return a SystemClock. Won't this cause a ClassCastException?

Comment: Thanks. Just fixed this.